# How to come up with the bibliography style I need

Tags: bibtex

I would like to replicate the following reference style:

> Martin, R.L. (1999), The new 'geographical turn' in economics: some critical reflections, *Cambridge Journal of Economics*, 23: 65-91

I am not sure what to use. I tried with `natbib` and `dcu` style, which gives me the following:

[image]

The above is pretty similar, the main differences are marked in the picture. Do you know which alterantive style I could use to obtain the style I need or, alternatively, how I could include the changes indicated in the picture?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The standard piece of advice given to people who are looking to replicate a given but unknown BibTeX bibliography style is to become familiar with the `makebst` utility that's part of the [custom-bib](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib?lang=en) package. Type `latex makbst` at a command promplt and proceed to answer a series of detailed questions, each with predefined multiple-choice answers. The result is a bespoke bibliography style file that implements your formatting needs perfectly.

Comment: Off-topic: Assuming the formatted bib entry shown in your screenshot was created with BibTeX, the author(s) made the (sadly depressingly common!) mistake of failing to encase the word `Bayesian` in curly braces; doing so would have informed BibTeX that the word should not be converted to lowercase.

Comment: @Mico. Thanks. I will follow your suggestion and have a look at custom-bib

Comment: @Mico. Thanks for pointing out the issue regarding the word Bayesian. Of course you are right. I did not edit the text, but indeed i should have {Bayesian}, rather than Bayesian.

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is the issue solved? How?